# regular expression problem (Pattern/Matcher)

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I need to find specific word on a string using regular expression.
rules :
before that word, I must not have a letter, a number or an underscore.
this word must be not followed by a letter, a number or an underscore.

Example :
I'm looking for the word 'the' in :
'Hi, it\'s a random text containing some words, the .the thingthe THE, tthe Tthe test_the@thesite.com'

in this string It must be found 3 times : the and .the and THE
so I must get true as a return.

my code :

```
String str = 'Hi, it\'s a random text containing some words, the .the thingthe THE, tthe Tthe test_the@thesite.com';
String var = 'the';
String s = '(?<![\\w])'+var.toUpperCase()+'(?![\\w])';
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(s);
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(str.toUpperCase());
System.debug('###matches : '+MyMatcher.matches());
```

Matches return always false.
I tried with this also :
 `'(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])'+var.toUpperCase()+'(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `matches` method will only return true if the entire input string matches the result. You want to use `find` instead, which will match a substring. Take a look at the `Matcher` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) for these methods:

> - find()
>     Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. This method returns true if a subsequence of the input sequence matches this Matcher object's pattern.
> - matches()
>     Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

So if you want to know whether your substring is contained anywhere in the input string, use `MyMatcher.find()` instead.

A couple side notes:

- If you want your expression to be case insensitive, set the `i` flag by starting your expression with `(?i)`.
- If you want to look for a *whole word*, wrap it in the *word boundary* character (`\b`), not backward and forward lookaheads for non-word characters.
- With the above in mind, I would change the expression to: `'(?i)\\b' + var + '\\b'`

Answer (score 0):

> before that word, I must not have a letter, a number or an underscore.

A `/W` is supposed to match any character that is not a word character (alphanumeric & underscore) and is equivalent to `(^A-Za-z0-9_)`.

That having been said, I think at the root of your issue is that you're using square brackets `[\\W]` in your code when apex is expecting parens `(\\W)` for your capture groups.

And as @Adrian Larson noted, you do need to use `MyMatcher.find()`.

Comment: Square brackets vs parens is definitely not the issue here. They're not trying to *capture* the surrounding non-word characters, they're trying to specifically ignore them. Also I think you got the wrong slash before your `W`. ;)

Comment: I looked at his code earlier and initially started to discuss non capture groups. He's using negative look aheads and negative look behinds rather than non-capture groups which would look like `(?:\\W)` NOT his `(?<![\\w])` and `(?![\\w])` which would seem to also be a problem. That would prevent him from finding what his IS looking for. The first slash needs to be escaped is why there's two. I don't believe it to be a forward slash, but I'd have to look at my apex code. The references show it as a backslash at http://regexr.com/

Comment: Yeah as you've basically noted yourself the brackets are entirely extraneous. In fact, I think having any type of capturing group or lookahead/lookbehind is completely extraneous. In this case there's no real difference between `(?:\W)` and `\W`.

Comment: Yes, exactly my point. His look aheads and behinds are preventing him from finding what he's looking for. When I initially read his question, I thought he was trying to find out what the look ahead and behind should be to find what to exclude to reveal what he wanted to find.

Comment: Have you tried the initial expression? It does work with `find`. It's inefficient, perhaps, but not flat out wrong. The matcher from the OP will find three groups.

Comment: I could only test the last half easily on gskinner's site. Look behinds aren't supported in javascript and I didn't want to spend time running it in Apex. The last half does work on his site if you substitute a `(the)` capture group.